# Javascript как прервать выполнение кода в if?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, допустим есть следующий код:

```
if(!a) {
 a = true;
 ..
 ..
}
```

И появилась необходимость не выполнять код в проверке. Как это сделать кроме комментирования его? Если бы это была функция, можно было просто сделать `return`, но не в этот раз.

Comment: Попробуйте полностью описать задачу, так как из вопроса не очень понятно что и для чего вы хотите.

Comment: @entithat Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в том, что мы заранее пишем условие, которое равно `false`. Но не уверен, что это будет быстрее и легче, чем внести код в комментарии.

Попробуйте сделать так.

```
if(false && (!a)) {
 a = true;
 ..
 ..
}
```

Или вот так.

```
try
{
 if(!a) {
     throw "Skip";
     a = true;
     ..
     ..
    }
}
catch(e){}
```